# Full text search with correct words only

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm coding a search function using `full-text-search` and I  want result to be shown only if the words typed are contained in table.

```
$search_value = $db->mysqli->real_escape_string("lana born to die sdkjfhsdkjfhdsjkfhdsjkfhd");

$query = "select * from `music` where match(`title`, `artist`) against ('$search_value')";
```

```
artist               title
----------------------------------
lana del rey    west coast
lana del rey    born to die
lana del rey    summertime sadness
lana del rey    blue jeans
```

For ex. if I search: `lana born to die sdkjfhsdkjfhdsjkfhdsjkfhd` it shows me `lana del rey born to die` as a result. This should not happen. 
I want it to show results only if you type for ex. `lana`, `lana del rey born` and so on.

Any ideas.

Comment: Why shouldn't that happen? It search term contains valid text, it just doesn't have an exact match.

Comment: It doesn't have to be exact match but if a particualr word is not containded in that result, the result should not be shown. @JayBlanchard

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130526/sql-server-full-text-search-for-exact-match-with-fallback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transform the query to have a boolean full-text search. This is done by adding a + or - in front of every word within the search query.

In this case, we add a + as this stands as an AND whereas a - stands as a NOT.

As such if you want to have it such that every word becomes required you could add the following code:

PHP:

```
$search_value = $db->mysqli->real_escape_string("lana born to die sdkjfhsdkjfhdsjkfhdsjkfhd");
$search_value = str_replace(" ", " +", $search_value);
$query = "select * from `music` where match(`title`, `artist`) against ('$search_value' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your query :

```
$query = "select * from `music` where `title` LIKE '%$search_value%'  
          OR `artist` LIKE '%$search_value%'";
```

I hope that will be help for you.

Comment: well searching with `LIKE` is not even close to `full-text-search` as performance keep that in mind. With MyISAM engine it could couse some table locks and more

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's issue as the query results that he doesn't want would still be returned.